# What's being said in these three audio clips? (7 seconds total)

Tags: translation

I'm trying to understand what's being said in these three audio clips.

[Clip 1](https://instaud.io/39CK) --> my english subtitles report as translation "show off". I'm trying to understand whether they mean to "make yourself visible", or "haughty" (the context makes both of them possible)

[Clip 2](https://instaud.io/39CL) --> My english subtitles report "The demolition crew moved in", but I can't understand here what does "moved in" mean.

[Clip 3](https://instaud.io/39CM) --> My english subtitles report "Important evidence is put by the trash bin", but I can't understand at all what does that mean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide longer audio for the first one?

Comment: There's nothing else being said near to that. The characters says it during a fight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The first one

> 섁똥 퍼문 씹……

Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what it means. Sounds like he's cursing in great anger, as it has quite a lot of tensed consonants for such a short speech. Could you provide longer audio?

It might not be in Korean; the accent is, though.

---

## The second one <sub>(was the easiest to catch words)</sub>

> “재개발한다고 철거 용역들이 들이닥치더라고.”
>
> (Thinking of the moment in the past) “Labor (demolition workers) showed up all of a sudden to carry out urban renewal.”

#### Noun “재개발” <sub>(“재- (re-)”＋“개발 (development)”)</sub> and verb “재개발하다”

“[Urban renewal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_renewal)” and “to carry out urban renewal.”

#### Conjugation “-ᆫ다고”

“Saying that; for reasons that.”

#### Noun (noun adjunct) “철거”

“Demolition.”

#### Noun “용역”

“Labor service” by definition, but often means “manual workers” as well.

#### Suffix “들”

A suffix denoting the plurals of nouns. “-s.”

#### Marker “이”

A subject marker.

#### Verb “들이닥치다”

“To arrive, come closer, especially suddenly or erratically.” Implies harshness. “To show up” would be a good translation.

#### Ending conjugation “-더라고”

Used when you describe something in retrospect.
“What I saw/realized/felt/learned was that; seemingly.”
Though I couldn't find such sense from the dictionary, this is used massively in casual conversations.

---

## The third one

> “중요한 단서는 쓰레기통의 옆에 두는 거라고.”
>
> “An important clue is what you put at the side of a trash can.”
>
> “You'd want to put your crucial clue next to your trash can.”
>
> (to make it look not so)

I couldn't recognize his “중요한” as his /ng/ and /n/ sounded a bit weak. I was like, “추요한다 해서는?” “추요한 단서는?” Now that I catch it, I'm writing this.

#### Adjective “중요하다”

“Of great importance.”

#### Noun “단서”

“Clue; a piece of evidence or information used in the detection of a crime or solving of a mystery.”

#### Marker (copula) “는”

“Is.”

#### Noun “쓰레기통” <sub>“쓰레기 (trash)”＋“통 (bin)”</sub>

“Trash can.”

#### Marker “의”

“Of.”

#### Noun “옆”

“Side; a position to the left or right of an object, place, or central point.”

#### Marker “에”

“At” or “on.”

#### Verb “두다”

“To put something down.”

#### Noun “거”

The informal or spoken variation of the word “것,” meaning a “thing.”

#### Ending conjugation “-라고”

Used in [the “해” register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_speech_levels#Hae-che) (the most casual speech level), to tell one's thought or opinion with a slight emphasizing or confidence.

Answer (score 1):

I recognized the movie from the second and third clip. 신과 함께-인과 연, or Along with the Gods: The Last 49 Days. And you know what? It's on Netflix. And you know what even more? Netflix provides Korean subtitles for this movie for its service in Korea.

So I went through the movie to find a scene where people fight, and located the sentence in question around 00:26:23. The subtitle reads:

> 새끼, 똥폼은, 씨...

I hear "이 새끼" with a determiner "이", but maybe that's a minor (and natural enough) addition by the actor, thus not reflected in the script-based subtitle.

**똥폼** in Standard Korean Dictionary:

> =개폼(본인은 멋있다고 생각하나, 일반적으로 못나다고 생각되는 자세를 낮잡아 이르는 말).

And in Korea University Korean Dictionary

> 실제로는 그렇지 않으면서 멋있는 척을 함을 얕잡아 이르는 말.

**씨** is just an exclamation here, and its SKD entry is:

> 마음에 차지 않거나 못마땅할 때 내는 소리. ‘시1’보다 센 느낌을 준다.

KUKD:

> 매우 못마땅하거나 마음에 차지 않을 때 내는 말.

Comment: So I would say a better translation (based on the surrounding context, not only the given sentence) would be something like: "Why the fxxx is he sitting like that?"

Comment: This is really useful! I didn't know about that Netflix thing.